# How to click on Required Radio button in the lists of Radio buttons using following method

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
<tr class="odd">
<td>
<input id="rightsTokenOid" type="radio" value="rightsTokenOid" onclick="setRightsTokenOid('urn:dece:rightstokenid:org:dece:E9807B96D4153534E040A8C0158E4EB8');" style="width:100%;border:0px" name="rightsTokenOid">
</td>
<td>urn:dece:rightstokenid:org:dece:E9807B96D4153534E040A8C0158E4EB8</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td>
<input id="rightsTokenOid" type="radio" value="rightsTokenOid" onclick="setRightsTokenOid('urn:dece:rightstokenid:org:dece:EA07E75226B329B1E040A8C0158E1813');" style="width:100%;border:0px" name="rightsTokenOid">
</td>
<td>urn:dece:rightstokenid:org:dece:EA07E75226B329B1E040A8C0158E1813</td>
</tr>
```

i m using following method to click on radio button but it is not working. Please Suggest me the way to click on the Required Radio Button using following method

```
String RightsTokenID = urn:dece:rightstokenid:org:dece:EA07E75226B329B1E040A8C0158E1813;

List<WebElement> radios = driver.findElements(By.name("rightsTokenOid"));

for (WebElement element : radios) {

    if (element.getAttribute("value").equals(RightsTokenID)) {
       element.click();
    }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`name`, `id` and `value` are identical for both radio buttons. Try giving them unique values.

Edit:
Try comparing `onclick`:

```
String RightsTokenID = "urn:dece:rightstokenid:org:dece:EA07E75226B329B1E040A8C0158E1813";

List<WebElement> radios = driver.findElements(By.name("rightsTokenOid"));

System.out.println("listsize: " + radios.size());
for (WebElement element : radios) {
    // just for debugging regarding this question
    System.out.println("tagname: " + element.getTagName());
    System.out.println("name: " + element.getAttribute("name"));
    System.out.println("type: " + element.getAttribute("type"));
    System.out.println("value: " + element.getAttribute("value"));
    System.out.println("onclick: " + element.getAttribute("onclick"));

    if (element.getAttribute("onclick").contains(RightsTokenID)) {
        element.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: the unique value is in onclick. how to pick that for clicking on radio button

Comment: Using duplicate ids is really bad practice. Can't you use the RightsTokenID string as id? Although it is quite long this would simplify the selection: `driver.findElement(By.id(RightsTokenID)).click();`

Comment: If you really want to go with the existing html you can use `element.getAttribute("onclick").contains(RightsTokenID)` in your loop.

Comment: Try the code in my answer. Mind the changes to `RightsTokenID` (added quotes) and the loop (`break` inside the if). Please post the output if it still fails.

Comment: @ ChristophT - it is printing **null**

Comment: Edited my code again. Please copy all of it into your class and post the output.

Comment: @ ChristophT -                                                      listsize: 2  
tagname: input   
name: rightsTokenOid  
 type: text  
value: 
onclick: null

Comment: Sorry, can't help you then - it works in my test. Btw: I'm using selenium version 2.36.0. If you have an older version try this one.

Comment: @  ChristophT - Let me try with new version of selenium server

Answer (score 0):

Use the help of position() in `xpath`

xpath for first radio button `//input[@id='rightsTokenOid']and position()=1`

xpath for second radio button `//input[@id='rightsTokenOid']and position()=2`

Comment: I am not comfortable using positional Xpath,I want to go ahead with above List and for loop method, the String RightsTokenID will be varying . so i want to pick that radio button

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Treat the onclick as an attribute and see if it's value has that correct token?

```
String RightsTokenID = urn:dece:rightstokenid:org:dece:EA07E75226B329B1E040A8C0158E1813;

List<WebElement> radios = driver.findElements(By.name("rightsTokenOid"));

for (WebElement element : radios) {

    if (element.getAttribute("onclick").contains(RightsTokenID)) {
       element.click();
    }
break;
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into an html page, and it's a bit difficult to do because the id (eg. <td>urn:dece:rightstokenid:org:dece:E9807B96D4153534E040A8C0158E4EB8</td>) don't seem to be attached to a html element when i look at it in firebug...is there a way to have the value of the input to have the id instead of rightsTokenOid? I was thinking of using preceding-sibling, but it's not working...